# Authorize.Net API: Define a default credit card for charging

Tags: asp.net, authorize.net

I have saved multiple Payment Profiles for a single customer in authorize.net. Each Payment Profile contains a credit card information.

I have two questions
1) Which credit card will be charge, When I am charging a transaction of customer who have      multiple Payment Profile.
2) Is there any way to define a default credit card to charge.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to create a default payment profile for payments. One must always be passed with each `createCustomerProfileTransactionRequest` call.

Answer (score 0):

in [updateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles-update-customer-payment-profile) page , I see this content:

defaultPaymentProfile : When set to true, this field designates the payment profile as the default payment profile. 
When a default payment profile has been designated, you can use getCustomerPaymentProfileRequest with customerProfileId as the only parameter.

Answer (score 0):

it will work 100% to set default payment profile

```
      $paymentprofile = new AnetAPI\CustomerPaymentProfileExType();
      $paymentprofile->setCustomerPaymentProfileId($payment_detail['payment_profile_id']);
      $paymentprofile->setBillTo($billto);
      $paymentprofile->setPayment($paymentCreditCard);
      $paymentprofile->setDefaultPaymentProfile($payment_detail['default_payment']);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers don't allow for UPDATING an existing payment profile but only CREATING a new payment profile. I know this is PHP but hopefully it will help someone, since I couldn't find anything related to this.

```
function paymentProfileUpdateDefault($profile_id, $payment_profile_id) {
    $success = false;
    $message = '';
    $error_message = '';

    // Create a merchantAuthenticationType object with authentication details
    $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
    $merchantAuthentication->setName($GLOBALS["authorizeNet"]["login_id"]);
    $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey($GLOBALS["authorizeNet"]["transaction_key"]);
    
    // Set the transaction's refId
    $refId = 'ref' . time();

    $request = new AnetAPI\GetCustomerPaymentProfileRequest();
    $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
    $request->setRefId($refId);
    $request->setCustomerProfileId($profile_id);
    $request->setCustomerPaymentProfileId($payment_profile_id);
    $controller = new AnetController\GetCustomerPaymentProfileController($request);

    // Get the response
    $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse($GLOBALS["authorizeNet"]["api_endpoint"]);
    if (($response != null) && ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == "Ok") ){           
        $billto = $response->getPaymentProfile()->getbillTo();
        $old_billto_obj = json_encode($billto, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
        $old_billto_arr = json_decode($old_billto_obj, true);

        $billto->setFirstName($old_billto_arr['firstName']);
        $billto->setLastName($old_billto_arr['lastName']);

    
        $old_paymentprofile = $response->getPaymentProfile();
        $old_paymentprofile_obj = json_encode($old_paymentprofile, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
        $old_paymentprofile_arr = json_decode($old_paymentprofile_obj, true);

        $creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
        $creditCard->setCardNumber( $old_paymentprofile_arr['payment']['creditCard']['cardNumber'] );
        $creditCard->setExpirationDate( $old_paymentprofile_arr['payment']['creditCard']['expirationDate'] );

        $paymentCreditCard = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
        $paymentCreditCard->setCreditCard($creditCard);
        
        $paymentprofile = new AnetAPI\CustomerPaymentProfileExType();
        $paymentprofile->setCustomerPaymentProfileId($payment_profile_id);
        $paymentprofile->setDefaultPaymentProfile(true); // Setting to default here
        $paymentprofile->setBillTo($billto);
        $paymentprofile->setPayment($paymentCreditCard);    

        // Submit a UpdatePaymentProfileRequest
        $request = new AnetAPI\UpdateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest();
        $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
        $request->setCustomerProfileId($profile_id);
        $request->setPaymentProfile($paymentprofile);

        $controller = new AnetController\UpdateCustomerPaymentProfileController($request);
        $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse($GLOBALS["authorizeNet"]["api_endpoint"]);
        if (($response != null) && ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == "Ok") ){
            $Message = $response->getMessages()->getMessage();
            $success = true;
        } else if ($response != null){
            $errorMessages_obj = $response->getMessages()->getMessage();
            $errorMessages_obj = json_encode($errorMessages_obj, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
            $errorMessages_arr = json_decode($errorMessages_obj, true);
            $error_message = $errorMessages_arr[0]['text'];    
            $message = 'There was an error'; 
        }

        
    } else {
        $errorMessages_obj = $response->getMessages()->getMessage();
        $errorMessages_obj = json_encode($errorMessages_obj, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
        $errorMessages_arr = json_decode($errorMessages_obj, true);
        $error_message = $errorMessages_arr[0]['text'];    
        $message = 'There was an error';
    }

    return array('success'=>$success, 'message'=>$message, 'error'=>$error_message, 'data'=>$old_paymentprofile_arr);
}
```